# Cygwin: git 2.33.0: gitk not showing diffs from index

Tags: git, cygwin

I have been using *Cygwin git* for a long time (since about 2012). Much better than *msysgit*, as *bash* and all utilities are identical to what runs on *linux*, which is where I deploy. I have lots of scripts that run on both platforms, and files are moved between the two using *git* - I hardly ever use *sftp*. I use *gitk* heavily when composing commit messages, so seeing the diffs between the index and HEAD is pretty important to me.

Anyway, I just got a new *Windows 10* PC, and installed *Cygwin* on it. *git* seemed to be working fine, until I made some changes and added the files to the index. Running *git status* shows the new and modified files correctly. Then when I run *gitk*, the main window shows "*Local changes to be committed*" above the master branch, as usual. And when I select "*Local changes to be committed*", then down in the lower right corner the *Comments* window for *Patch* shows the pathnames for each of the new or modified files in the index. All good. But the lower left window, showing the line diffs for each file is empty after the boilerplate lines:

```
Author:   
Committer:   
Parent: c7d3fb6f37a88e6d00c56517e466661fd0a7bd57 (Bugs in pbUser: we no longer use names_by_email or passwds_by_email arrays...)
Branch: 
Follows: 
Precedes: 

    Local changes checked in to index but not committed
```

And clicking a pathname in the lower right window does not show the diffs for that file. But running *git diff --cached* shows the correct output.

I looked a little at the changes announced in Cygwin-announce Digest, Vol 21, Issue 3, and see that *Version 2.33.1-1 of Git* includes changes to *gitk*. but I can't trudge through the sources to try to guess what might have caused this - it clearly can't be a documented "feature". Anyone else having this problem, or have a clue about it? I can't imagine how it can be user error, but it so often turns out that way, I have to wonder...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess it wasn't user error, but rather a bug that slipped out. Rereading my question, I realized that I said Cygwin-announce Digest, Vol 21, Issue 3 reported changes to *gitk* in *git 2.33.1-1*, but I was complaining about *git 2.33.0*. So I just went back to Cygwin's `setup-x86_64.exe` and installed the pending updates, which included *git 2.33.1-1* (it also lists *gitk 2.33.1-1*). Now *gitk* works correctly, as it always did!

This is great, but leads to a new issue, in that *git --version* still reports *2.33.0*. Given that it isn't practical to install Cygwin correctly and maintain it without using the installer, I guess that's not really worth complaining about...